# Powershell Group-object array list

Tags: arrays, powershell, group-by, count

Two comma separated item added in array list and I would like to group them to count the total.

```
$list_distinct = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$list_distinct.Add("Site A,Item A")
$list_distinct.Add("Site A,Item A")
$list_distinct.Add("Site A,Item B")
$list_distinct.Add("Site B,Item C")
$list_distinct.Add("Site B,Item D")
$list_distinct.Add("Site B,Item D")
```

Tried this:

```
$test = $list_distinct | Group-Object Values
```

The result shows Count (the whole total), Name(empty) and Group (the whole added items).

Any way to fix this? Or is there any better method?

Desired output example:

```
Site   | Item   | Count
Site A | Item A |   2
Site A | Item B |   1
Site B | Item C |   1
Site B | Item D |   2
```

Comment: Can you show your desired output for this? Your array list just contains strings. Group object has no metrics with which to coordinate this. Sounds like you want a collection of site and item objects instead.

Comment: @Matt added desired output example. Collection of site and item objects? Googling it now.

Comment: `Site A | Item A |   3` should be 2 correct?

Comment: Ah yes. Edited. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither the `ArrayList` object nor its elements have a property `Values`. Non-existent properties are expanded to an empty result, so all of your values are grouped under the same (empty) name.

Change this

```
$list_distinct | Group-Object Values
```

into this

```
$list_distinct | Group-Object
```

and the problem will disappear.

For your desired output you will also need to split the values and create new (custom) objects:

```
$list_distinct | Group-Object | ForEach-Object {
    $site, $item = $_.Name -split ','
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Site'  = $site
        'Item'  = $item
        'Count' = $_.Count
    }
} | Select-Object Site, Item, Count
```

The trailing `Select-Object` is to enforce field order since PowerShell hashtables aren't ordered by default.

In PowerShell v3 and newer you can simplify that to

```
$list_distinct | Group-Object | ForEach-Object {
    $site, $item = $_.Name -split ','
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Site'  = $site
        'Item'  = $item
        'Count' = $_.Count
    }
}
```

The trailing `Select-Object` isn't needed here, because the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator implicitly uses an ordered hashtable.

Comment: removing property 'Value' gives me the result so much closer to what i needed. Incredible!